# How to deal with empty values in a cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, missing-data

I'm currently working on my master's thesis. Part of the work is a customer segmentation by means of a cluster analysis. 
One variable for the cluster determination should be the chronological sequence of purchased product categories. For example, customer 10 has bought at first product category A, then product category C and at last an article from the group X. This means the changing of the purchase behavior of the customers should be included in the analysis.

Now the question is:  what will be the best way to map the data? My idea was to divide this criterion in different variables. I wanted to create a new variable for each purchase of a new category made. So finally I get the variable "first sold category" to "10th sold category". These variables can take the value of the category names.

The problem with this approach  is, that each customer buys a different number of products. If a customer buys 3 different product categories, there will be in the first 3 columns the desired values and in the remaining columns will be no value. Due to the fact that the various distance measures in the clustering algorithms cannot handle missing values, I am now at a loss. Is there another method to map the criterion or a possibility of using empty values?

Comment: This question is not as much about clustering itself as it is about  choosing (or developing) an appropriate distance measure to compare _sequences_ or _trajectories_, and those potentially being of different lengths. There can exist plenty of literature on that. I'm not an expert. However, here's just one approach (work-stub, it can be developed in various ways). Imagine that the list of potential products is limited and not huge, then the presence and the sequence of them for a respondent can be formatted as square matrix with values either 0 (not present) or integer...

Comment: [cont.] equal to the lead/lag of one product relative another. Say, possible products are `a,b,c,d`. Respondent with data b->a->d will produce matrix values `(ab)=1, (ba)=-1, (ad)=-1, (da)=1, (bd)=-2, (db)=2, and 0 for the rest of the cells`. Then you can compare such matrices between all the respondents pairwisely, like usual data (unwrap matrices into vectors), computing some similarity mearure (for example, cosine). You can additionally adjust for the different sparsity of the matrices (= different sequence lenght) whichever way looks wise to you.

Comment: Dear @Markus , could you possibly indicate what is the ulitmate purpose of your clustering? That means: what will you use the clusters for? Thank you for any clarification.